# Chrome on ubuntu 12.04 cannot render icons on github

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, github

I am using chrome, and when I browse github, instead of the icons I get either empty squares or a literal "fi" symbol.  Firefox renders them properly. It's clear that these icons are not images but from a fontset, and there's some mixup either in the encoding or the fontset so that the result is not rendered. I tried to tinker with various values in the chrome configuration but I got nowhere.

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the origin of the problem, but I solved by resetting Chrome.